# How to wrap the known text in span while on its row-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="foo">
    <div>first row</div>
    <div>if(b<3 && b>0)</div>
    <div>third row</div>
    <div>if(b<3 && b>0)</div>
</div>
```

I have loop that goes through the four inside divs. i am currently inside the 2nd row and detected `if` and also able to get the text that i wanted to be wrapped in span

```
var wrapCond = 'b<3 && b>0';
```

I wanted to wrap the content of wrapCond considering that im on the 2nd row. I need to wrap it while on the 2nd loop because i will assigned a `class` for the span-wrapping. It must be something like this:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div>first row</div>
    <div>if(<span>b<3 && b>0</span>)</div>
    <div>third row</div>
    <div>if(b<3 && b>0)</div>
</div>
```

JS (just a representation)

```
  for( var x=0; x<inlineDiv_num; x++ ){
       var inlineDiv_num_textL = inlineDiv_num_text.length;
       for( var y=0; y<inlineDiv_num_textL; y++){

          if( /\s+if$/.test(kword_search) ){

          var kwordSyntaxSearch = sliceToEndString(x,y);
          var wrapCond = kwordSyntaxSearch.slice(kwordSyntaxSearch.indexOf('(')+1, kwordSyntaxSearch.indexOf('{')-1);

           //HERE I NEED TO WRAP wrapCond here

          }

       }
 }
```

I didnt show all my code because its too long. Unclear? just comment ^^

**NOTE**: I am on the 2nd loop but i want this also to happen in the 4th where it finds `if`

i need something that uses eq, so that replacement will only occur at the row not all replacement at single

Comment: Please post the jQuery that you tried.

Comment: So the second and fourth rows get wrapped, or only the second row? And if only the second row, why?

Comment: 2nd and 4th, as long as it find if,

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#foo div').each(function (idx) {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/b<3 && b>0/, '<span>b<3 && b>0</span>'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2vQCt/)**

Comment: can i place this inside the row loops?

Comment: You should be able to use this chunk of code by itself. You tagged your question with jQuery, are you not using it?

Comment: I am using jquery. I mean can i place it inside y cond or x cond?

Comment: i need something that uses eq, so that replacement will only occur at the row not all replacement at single call